# How to make menus open "fully" by default in MS Word 2003?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

Some windows apps (MS Office 2003 actually) have a feature which I find annoying where when you first open the menu, only a subset of the menu items are shown.  Double clicking the menu or clicking the arrow at the bottom expands the rest of the menu.  I still find it annoying.

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in MS-Word, it's Tools >> Customize >> Options and check the box for "Always show full menus"

Comment: Office is the main culprit, though it no longer applies in 2007 (ribbon bar), and I think if you set it in any one of the apps it applies to the whole suite.

Comment: @[GalacticCowboy]: hey, you're right! I turned it off in Word and it's off in Excel, too.